# pythonでメールファイルから本文の指定部分のみを抽出したい

Tags: python, python3, 正規表現

お世話になります。
このように過去に自分が送信したメールの返事で、
自分の書いた文も書いてあるメールファイルがあり、

```
≪^------------------　××様へ------------------------    
〇月〇日の詳細：
［場所］△△ホール
［持ち物］特になし
 備考
  当日は公共機関をご利用ください。
 ---------------------------------------------------^≫
是非お越しください




-----Original Message-----
From:〇×
Sent: Mondey
To: ☆×
Subject: 日程について

こんにちは
下記のような形で日程を教えてください
≪^------------------　〇〇へ------------------------
 〇月〇日の詳細：
［場所］××ホール
［持ち物］特になし
 備考
  〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇
 ---------------------------------------------------^≫
```

一番上の「××様へ」の中身である

> △△ホール
>   特になし
>   当日は公共機関をご利用ください。

のみをコマンドプロンプト上に出力させたいと思い、他の方が過去に質問された内容や、
自分が正規表現について質問した際に頂いた答えをもとにこのように書いてみたのですが、

```
import ExtractMsg
import re
from glob import glob
import sys
args = sys.argv

for filename in glob(r"{}/*.msg".format(args[1])):
    msg = ExtractMsg.Message(filename)
    msg_message = msg.body
    m = re.search('(.*)(^≪^.*-)(.*)(^-.*^≫)(.*)', msg_message, flags 
(re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE))
    if m :
        x = re.sub('\［.*\］', "", m.group())
        print(x)
    else:
        pass
```

何も出力されず、困っている状態です。下の

「〇月〇日の詳細：
［場所］××ホール
［持ち物］特になし
 備考
  〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇
がメール内に書いてある場合にそれを出力しない」

というコーディングができればよいなと思ったのですが、
いまいちどうやればよいかわかりません。
ご教授頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: 「一番上の〇〇様への中身である〜のみをコンパイル上に出力させたい」ということであれば、`m = re.search('\n［場所］\s*(.+?)\n(.|\n)*?［持ち物］\s*(.+?)\n(.|\n)*?備考(\s|\n)*(.+?)\n', msg_message, re.MULTILINE)` として、「［場所］」は `m.group(1)`, 「［持ち物］」は `m.group(3)`, 「備考」は `m.group(6)` になります。ただ、メールファイルの文字コードが UTF-8 以外(例えば ISO-2022-JP など)ですとマッチしません。もしかすると `ExtractMsg.Message` メソッドで文字コードの変換が自動で行われている可能性もありますけれども。

Comment: @metropolis

ありがとうございます。
備考が複数行になるかもしれない場合はまた違う正規表現の記述の仕方になるのでしょうか。

Comment: はい、その場合は、`'\n［場所］\s*(.+?)\n(.|\n)*?［持ち物］\s*(.+?)\n(.|\n)*?備考(\s|\n)*((.|\n)+?)\n\s*-+'` になります。ただし、「備考」が最後の項目である事が前提条件になります。

Comment: @metropolis
毎度ご丁寧にありがとうございます。
思い通りの処理ができたと思ったのですが、もし抜き出したい文の中身が`≪^------------------　××様へ------------------------    
    

    いまだ未定
    
    
     ---------------------------------------------------^≫`
 など、re.searchに引っかからない文が送信されてきた場合は、 
  本来抜き出したくない部分である
  
  　`〇月〇日の詳細：
［場所］××ホール
［持ち物］特になし
備考
〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇`

が抜き出せてしまったりするのでしょうか。その場合は

`text = """
  　〇月〇日の詳細：
［場所］××ホール
［持ち物］特になし
備考
〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇
"""`
このようにその部分の文章を変数に入れ、「もしtextがメール全体に入っていたら、出力しない」
という処理が必要になるでしょうか。

Comment: はい、その通りです。対策としては引用開始を示す `-----Original Message-----` を使うとよいかもしれません。`\n［場所］\s*(.+?)\n(.|\n)*?［持ち物］\s*(.+?)\n(.|\n)*?備考(\s|\n)*((.|\n)+?)-+\^≫(.|\n)+?-+Original Message-+`

Comment: @metropolisありがとうございます！
まだまだ正規表現の理解度は低いですが、なんとかプログラムを完成させることができそうです。ご協力感謝いたします！

Answer (score 1):

「正規表現を使わなければいけない」というのでなければ、愚直に実装するのもありかと。デバッグしてないので動作確認してないですが。

```
with open(file, "r") f:
  lines = f.readlines()

stat = 0

for line in lines:
  if stat == 0:
    if line.startwith("［場所］"):
      print line.strip("［場所］")
      stat = 1
  if stat == 1:
    print line.strip("［持ち物］")
    stat = 2
  if stat == 2:
    # 「備考」を読み飛ばす
    stat = 3
    continue
  if stat == 3:
    print line
    stat = 0
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！
今回はできれば正規表現を用いたいと思っていたのですが、
今後作成するプログラムに利用できそうです。参考にさせていただきます。